# Using matlab to add contacts to outlook

Tags: matlab, outlook, contacts

I have an .xls file containing a large amount of emails, which i want to add to outlook via matlab. Processing the .xls file is no problem.

I found it is possible to send mails via matlab using 
    `h = actxserver('outlook.Application'`and i figured i might be able to use this for my purpose. I'm however completely unfamiliar with the ActiveX/COM interface, and how to use it.

I tried to use get(h) but that did not give me any useful information.

Two questions. Specifically 1) how can i use Matlab to add contacts.

And secondly, more general, how would i be able to find out what i can do with 'h' in this case? I see people using `h.Subject` or `h.To` How would i be able to find out the possible things (like Subject or To)  i can do with h?

Comment: this has got to be one of the weirdest questions I've ever seen. If you have a .xls file with emails, why don't you just use outlook, what does matlab offer that outlook or others does not?

Comment: Right, good question. The .xls file comes straight from human resources, and it needs a lot of processing before it's usable. Specifically i'm asking this question because i want to learn how to do this via Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a contact you need to create a [`ContactItem` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867603.aspx) through the ActiveX control:

```
h = actxserver('outlook.Application');

newContact = h.CreateItem('olContactItem');
newContact.FirstName = 'John';
newContact.LastName = 'Smith';
newContact.Email1Address = 'john.smith@email.email';
newContact.Save();

% newContact.Display;  % To check your work
h.release;  % Close the ActiveX interface
```

See the [`ContactItem` properties page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.contactitem_properties.aspx) for a list of other fields you can modify.

For the general question, it just takes some poking around in [Outlook's Object Model Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208225(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: This already helped me a lot. Would there be any way to set the adress group it needs to go into? I'm automatically signed into two emails acounts on Outlook. I require the contacts to be added to one specific email accounts, and preferably to one specific contact group.

Comment: I'm not sure, sorry. You can create a new contact group with `h.CreateItem('olDistributionListItem');` but I can't seem to work out how to actually add contacts to it without MATLAB erroring out with a very unhelpful message.

Answer (score 1):

I would still suggest using outlook for sending the emails so you have all the up-to-date functionalities, and MS is constantly updating office 365 and it would not be the first time when an MS interface was screwed up by microsoft update.

In any case, you are right, there is a active X interface that can be used, before you use it, you have to run matlab using administrator privilege (if you are on windows) and make sure you have a Matlab version > 2010 rb (the version I am testing on).

if you are using h = actxserver('outlook.Application') all this does is create an OLE server with the given application ID, so get() will not grab you anything other than version number and server ID etc. However, it should enable you to call on functions belonging to that server (i.e. the functionality of outlook.Application, so in general, to send an email :

```
mail = h.CreateItem('olMail');
mail.Subject = subject;
mail.To = to;
mail.BodyFormat = 'olFormatHTML';
mail.HTMLBody = body;
% Add attachments, if specified.
 if nargin == 4
    for i = 1:length(attachments)
        mail.attachments.Add(attachments{i});
    end
 end
 % Send message and release object.
mail.Send;
h.release;
```

Note the above code was taken from [Mathworks](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94446-can-i-send-e-mail-through-matlab-using-microsoft-outlook), I did not write them and probably would never try... but it has been tested to work on my local station.

To answer your second question, what functions you can call on depends on what functions are available in outlook.Application, this is available from [microsoft application dev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863377.aspx), which are all the functions you can call from the object.

Also note, all parameters are passed as STRINGS to the Object through the OLE, so there is no Matlab functionality here and you cannot use any of the Matlab functionality in calls with the Object, if you want to do something clever - you need to pass VB language through as strings to the Object.